# Flash player problems in Chrome on Linux Mint 12

Tags: linux, google-chrome, linux-mint, flash-player, adobe-flash

I have pretty funny problem with flash player, I can view movies from youtube, but flash does not save my usage data and don't let me change prefferences. Problem occurs only if I install adblock and quake live plugin on firefox before installing chrome. Removing/pruning flash and firefox doesn't help. How could I reverse installing those plugins so I can have working flash on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with permissions.

From my experience, latest Ubuntu has a program called `apparmor` which doesn't give some programs (like MySQL Server) access to local storage. Try searching Google for manuals.